# 301 redirect on sub domain

Tags: redirect

To handle 301 redirect we have made changes in pipeline and written following class

```
public class CustomRedirect301 : PreprocessRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
    {
        var targeturl = objDB.GetTargetURL(args.Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });)
        args.Context.Response.RedirectPermanent(targeturl, true);
    }
}
```

In GetTargetURL function we pass incoming URL part only after domain 
for example incoming request is **www.mysite.com/healthcare** we pass **/healthcare** and this function return actual url where user should redirect let's say **www.mysite.com/part-1/part-2/healthcare**

We maintain this mapping in database table with two column UrlFrom and UrlTo so in this case

UrlFrom is /healthcare

UrlTo is www.mysite.com/part-1/part-2/healthcare

But now we have one request where we have to redirect **abc.mysite.com** to **www.mysite.com/part-1/part-2/part-3**

In this case we don't have any URL part after domain to pass as input parameter in GetTargetURL function so how can we achieve this.

Environment: Sitecore 8.1 MVC / Multisite implementation

Comment: Assuming that this is a single case and you don't need to be able to edit this frequently, you can use `url rewrite module`.

Comment: in place of rewrite module we implemented this so we are not using url rewrite module anymore now that's why we are looking for other way

Comment: Have you considered using [**aliases**](https://sdn.sitecore.net/articles/administration/aliases.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `URL Rewrite Module` (and from your comment I see you don't want it), you need to change the code of your processor slightly.

Add an entry like

```
UrlFrom ://abc.mysite.com
UrlTo www.mysite.com/part-1/part-2/part-3
```

and call `GetTargetURL` as you do now:

```
var key = args.Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });

// for "abc.mysite.com" key will be an empty string
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
{
    // for "abc.mysite.com" it will return "://abc.mysite.com"
    key = string.Format("://" + Request.Url.DnsSafeHost);
}
var targeturl = objDB.GetTargetURL(key);
```

If you do this like that, you don't need to write any custom code that will check if domain is `abc.mysite.com`. And you will be able to add more subdomain redirects without any code changes.

One important thing is: you need to make should that either your database call are really efficient or cached. You don't want to make a call to database for every home page request if it's not necessary.

Comment: yeah I think for particular this case first I have to check the value of **args.Context.Request.Url** . If it's **abc.mysite.com** then I will pass **args.Context.Request.Url** in GetTargetURL() function. In this function we will check if UrlFrom entry and will return UrlTo value...Is it correct?

Comment: Answer updated. More code with working solution added.